# How can I convert Java object to Json in spray routing

Tags: java, json, scala, spray, spray-routing

I would like to know if there is any way to return Java object as Json String inside spray routing.

For now, I am converting my Java object (which is returned my UserActor) into Json using Jackson through a util class(JacksonUtil) created by me.

Here is the code snippet for reference :

```
val route = {
    path("users" / Segment) { id =>
      parameterMap { params =>
        get {
          respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`text/plain`) {
            val resource: GetResource = new GetResource
            resource.searchCriteriaList.add(new SearchCriteria("userId", "=", Segment)) 
            logger.info("Request Received in new route: " + resource)
            onComplete(callUserActor(resource)) {
              case Success(ret: User) => {
                logger.info("Request complete. Success.")
                complete(JacksonUtil.toJson(ret))
              }
              case Failure(error) => {
                logger.info("Request complete. Failure. " + error)
                complete("Error: " + error)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }

def callUserActor(getResource: GetResource): Future[User] = {
    (userActor ? getResource).mapTo[User]
  }
```

GetResource is the class which take of query parameters.
For example if client hits GET /users/123, then GetResource will add a searchcriteria as userId = "123"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do it by yourself like by using **Jackson** or using **LiftJson** as per your needs and ease of Use. Spray does not provide such feature by default as it does not have dependencies for this !

You can see the compile dependencies used by spray here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.spray/spray-routing_2.11/1.3.4

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, as simple as:

```
class YourService(implicit val requestTimeout: Timeout)
extends HttpServiceActor with
   Json4sJacksonSupport {

  path("users" / Segment) { id =>
    parameterMap { params =>
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`text/plain`) {
          val user : Future[User] = Future { User("name", "90") }
          complete(user)
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }

  implicit def json4sJacksonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats.lossless
}
```